# Python Scrapy Error. Running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported

Tags: scrapy

I made a script in Scrapy Python which has been working fine during months (without changes). Recently when I execute the script in Windows Powershell it raises the next error:

```
scrapy crawl spider –o 'filename.csv' –t 'csv'
```

...

```
Running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported
```

I wonder what the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: weird error, never seen that ... do you have multiple spiders in `spiders` folder?

Comment: Not, I don't. I only have one spider in spiders folder.

Comment: Try running the command without quotes (`'`), i.e. `scrapy crawl spider -o filename.csv -t csv`

Comment: I have tried that option and it does not work

Answer (score 6):

When you experience this, most probably you have an **extra space** somewhere in the params and crawler sees more params than expected.

Remove it and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you write the command option with the short dash: -o and not –o.
I tried copying and pasting your command and did not work, but it works with short dashes.

Comment: It does not work. Could this issue be related to use of pipelines (that executes more than one request at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I fixed it by changing:

`scrapy crawl s-mart -o test 2.csv -t csv`

To:

`scrapy crawl s-mart -o test2.csv -t csv`

So I am guessing that the whitespace was causing this?

Comment: I had the same problem as the original poster and I double checked the run-time arguments.  Extra whitespace was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Run command without `-t`, it's shortcut for generating new spiders based on pre-defined templates:

```
scrapy genspider [-t template] <name> <domain>
```

Try something like:

```
scrapy crawl <yourspidername> –o filename.csv
```

Documentation https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.10.3/topics/commands.html#available-tool-commands

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
scrapy crawl spider –o filename.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

try changing the name of your spider in its module. Maybe you have created a same named spider somewhere else or copied it, and scrapy keeps track of what you gave run in the past, thus it encounters 2+ spiders with same name and since name must be unique, it can't crawl it

Changing the name solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after I renamed my spider. 
The solution was to delete all the *.pyc files in the spiders folder.
These get regenerated by python compiler when you next run scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a "\n" in the parameter.
...replace("\n","")

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error. I changed the small o to a capital O and it worked for me.

scrapy crawl spider –O 'filename.csv' –t 'csv'

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, maybe you need to try this:

```
scrapy crawl nameSpider -o nameFile.csv
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.